# What is the best way to track iOS SDK usage?

Tags: ios, sdk, app-store-connect

I would like to get a statistics on how many people are using SDK that I'm providing. What functions they use the most and etc.

For apps I used firebase/fabric in order to track all that. But those services come with a responsibility (privacy policy). And if I just pack them into SDK that may conflict with people apps who don't want any tracking SDK being included in their Apps.

So the question is, are there any services that provides SDK tracking without violating privacy policy of user data collecting?

So far I was not able to find any of those specifically for SDK.

As a side question, If such analytics is taken place in SDK, should it be explicitly written in SDK description?. And should the people who integrate such SDK **explicitly write** in their app description that particular SDK is collecting their usage?